# Swift: Modifying one element in Array of Dictionaries

Tags: swift3, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an Array of dictionaries like this:

```
{
Place = "somewhere";
Type = Any;
timeRegisted = "2017-04-24T16:15:00";
},
```

I'm modifying the timeRegisted from UTC to local time. Like this:

```
let newJsonContent = jsonContent { (contents:Any) -> String in

            let dict:NSDictionary = contents as! NSDictionary
            let time:String = dict.object(forKey: "SchedDepTime") as! String
            print(time)

            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
            dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")! as TimeZone
            let date = dateFormatter.date(from: time)
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"
            dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
            let timeStamp = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
            return time
        }
```

The conversion of UTC to local time works great but my question to guys. How can just modify the time and keep the contents of the dictionary and not just the times?

Any of you knows how can I do this?
I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Unrelated but don't use `NSDictionary` or `NSTimeZone`. Use a Swift dictionary and `TimeZone`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all return dictionary instead of time.

```
let dict:NSDictionary = contents as! NSDictionary
.
. //Do any modifications here
.
return dict
```

Second you are not modifying anything in the code above. To modify you will need mutable dictionary.

```
var dict:NSDictionary = contents as! NSDictionary
```